# SSRS - How to carry on a summed total through multiple pagebreaks

Tags: reporting-services, sum, report, constants

Say for example, my parameters range between jan 2010 and july 2010, I have my report set up so that there is a page full of tickets for each month (6 pages). I have set up a total amount on the bottom of each page, which displays how much money the tickets spent for the entire month. Say for example, January 2010 there was $25,000 and in February 2010 there was $31,000 and in March $10,000. As my report stands right now, Each of the total amounts at the bottom of each page contain only the amount for the given month, I would want to see January say **$25,000** and I would want februarys total amount to say (Jan($25,000))+ **$31,000**, so **$56,000.**, I would then want March to have a total of the months Jan and Feb plus whatever amount the month of march spent (in this scenario, $10,000) So the Total amount, on the page for March, should read **$66,000.**, continued through every page.

I do not have sample code to provide however I have been attempting to research this I am just lost as to how to explain it to a search engine.

Comment: Where is this month total value displayed? In a tablix group header/footer row? What expression are you using?

Comment: not in a group, i just added a row to the bottom of my table and gave it a [sum(value)].

Comment: but obviously that will just add all of the rows within the cost total column... and display it in the textbox beside(To the right of) total amount:

Comment: would pictures assist you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally for something like this you would use an expression with RunningValue, i.e. something like:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!MyField.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```

or

```
=RunningValue(Fields!MyField.Value, Sum, "MyDataSet")
```

See [RunningValue Function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

The most important thing to check is the Scope variable here - I would start with the first option, i.e. `Nothing`, but depending on your report setup this might need to be something like the Dataset or the Tablix.

Comment: you are corrent with option 1, I appreciate your voluntary assistance while knowing damn well I can't provide you with rep points.. you are an awesome person.

Comment: I require 15 rep points to upvote or I would have already, I'll work on getting them and come back to these questions in the future and give you up votes!